# How to use node-imap and Meteor together?

Tags: node.js, imap, meteor

I'm looking for a way to access an IMAP mail account like Gmail and using Meteor.  I found node-imap but since it's an NPM module I've had a hard time getting NPM modules to work in Meteor.

Is there a good way to access an IMAP account using Meteor?

Comment: Have you got any npm modules to work yet? with `var require = meteor_bootstrap.require` to expose the `require` function (server side only)

Comment: I have not been able to get it work with just var require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require;  I followed the Coderwall tip in the response below, and it finally worked!

Comment: sorry about that it was a typo, bad copy paste on my part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a fun one.
I had exactly that as an example, see [my repository for it on GitHub](https://github.com/AVGP/meteordesk)

In short: Follow [this Coderwall tip](https://coderwall.com/p/2fveyq) to install the node-imap module.
Then in your meteor code:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  var require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require;
  var imap = require('imap');
```

and put the actual code in the

```
Meteor.startup(function() { ... });
```

call on the server side.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same trouble as described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/meteor-core/ZlPPrH7SqrE).

Instead of `__meteor_bootstrap__.require` use `Npm.require`.

Comment: Meteor 1.7> I get `TypeError: _require is not a function` when using `Npm.require`

Answer (score 0):

This could be useful
https://atmospherejs.com/epaminond/imap

Install

```
meteor add epaminond:imap
```

Usage

This is how it's used in regular node

```
var Imap = require('imap');
```

To use in *Meteor* with this package you can just access global *Imap* variable.

Comment: It would be nice to put your command line actions and code into code formatting by either indenting with 4 spaces or use the code button (the one with the curly braces) to make this answer proper.